# How to find words with Capital Letter using sed

Tags: sed

I want to print "Found" whenever a word with Initial Capital letter is found in a file using sed.

I have tried with the following approach

```
s/\b[A-Z]\w*\s*/FOUND/g
/FOUND/d
```

But it is not working. It just replace every word with Found.

Please tell me where I am wrong

Comment: Can you provide an example input and expected output? It's not clear to me what the output should be exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**print FOUND for line havind a capital starting word inside**

```
sed -e 's/^/ /;/[^[:alnum:]_-][A-Z]/ !d' -e 's/.*/FOUND: &/' YourFile
```

- adapt the class `[^[:alnum:]_-]` to specify what is autorised as word start edge (here is not a digit, letter, `-` and `_` so `;` is available and `;Ok` is found
- adapt secont part (second `-e` action) to whatever you want with the line (here it replace all the line by `FOUND`)

**print FOUND in place of every capital letter word**

```
sed -e 's/^/ /' -e ':cycle' -e 's/\([^[:alnum:]_-]\)[A-Z][[:alnum:]-_]*/\1FOUND/g;t cycle' -e 's/.//' YourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\n/!s/\b[[:upper:]]\S*/\nFOUND\n/g;/^FOUND/P;D' file
```

Replace every word beginning with a capital with `\nFOUND\n` (do this only once per line hence the non-match `\n`) and print only those strings that begin with `FOUND` reducing the line until it is empty. Then repeat on the next line etc.

Answer (score -1):

file:

```
Hi there

My Name is Ian
and I am Have no Worries
```

Split the file into words, replace each word starting with a capital with `Found` and the print out all the `Found`s while leaving out the rest:

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' file | sed 's/^[A-Z].*/Found/;/^Found/ !d'
```

Edit: Thanks goes to NeronLeVelu for pointing out `cat` and `grep` was unnecessary

Comment: lot of pipe (fist cat is not needed, sed could directly take the file as last argument). Last sed could also directly act as grep. Using your code: `sed 's/ /\n/g' file | sed 's/^[A-Z].*/Found/;/^Found/ !d'`

Comment: Thanks @NeronLeVelu for help!